# How to combine multiple Observable values via forkjoin to result in a single value Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

Trying to get an `Observable<boolean>` for my Guard by combining two `Observable<boolean>` values via a `forkJoin`.

I've tried this approach before:

```
    isAllowedToEditSession(sessionId: number): Observable<boolean> {
        const isAllowed$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
        const hostName = this.authService.getMyDisplayName();
        this.sessionProxyService.getSessionById(sessionId).subscribe(session => {
          if (session.hostName === hostName) {
            isAllowed$.next(true);
          }
        });
        this.userService.isUserAdmin().subscribe(isAdmin => 
   isAllowed$.next(isAdmin));
        return isAllowed$.asObservable();
      }
```

It worked, but only because `this.userService.isUserAdmin()` is a `BehaviorSubject` and had a value stored already, so it ran synchronously.

This is my current approach, which does not get me the result I'd hoped for.

```
isAllowedToEditSession(sessionId: number): Observable<boolean> {
    const hostName = this.authService.getMyDisplayName();
    const isAllowed$ = forkJoin(
      this.sessionProxyService.getSessionById(sessionId),
      this.userService.isUserAdmin()
    ).pipe(
      map(([session, isAdmin]) => {
        const isHost = session.hostName === hostName;
        console.log(isHost || isAdmin);
        return isHost || isAdmin;
      })
    );
    return isAllowed$;
  }
```

`isAllowed$` is recognised as `Observable<boolean>` but it does not correctly emit those values.

**UPDATE**

This works (see accepted answer for explanation):

```
isAllowedToEditSession(sessionId: number): Observable<boolean> {
    const hostName = this.authService.getMyDisplayName();
    const isAllowed$ = forkJoin(
      this.sessionProxyService.getSessionById(sessionId), //pipe(take(1)) not needed here
      this.userService.isUserAdmin().pipe(take(1))
    ).pipe(
      map(([session, isAdmin]) => {
        const isHost = session.hostName === hostName;
        return isHost || isAdmin;
      })
    );
    return isAllowed$;
  }
```

Comment: How does this not work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the expected behavior. This does not work because it does not emit true even though either `isHost`or `isAdmin`should return true in my use case. But the accepted answer was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forkJoin` requires all source Observables to emit at least one value and then complete. And that's the problem you have. You're using `BehaviorSubject` underneath which doesn't complete until you call `.complete()` on it.

You should do for example this:

```
if (session.hostName === hostName) {
  isAllowed$.next(true);
  isAllowed$.complete();
}
```

So it depends on how `getSessionById()` and `isUserAdmin()` are implemented. You could also pipe both of them with `take(1)` before passing them into `forkJoin`.

Comment: Thank you! That was my problem. I have a question though, do http calls automatically complete? Because I did not have to `.pipe(take(1))` on `this.sessionProxyService.getSessionById(sessionId)` which is a get call. I updated my post with the final solution.

Comment: Yes, if you mean `HttpClient` in Angular they complete automatically.